# R: nested data from XML as tibble and convert nested nodes to json string

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, tidyverse, tibble

I'm stuck at work with a code problem in R that I can't solve. I have the following XML Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Votacion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://opendata.camara.cl/camaradiputados/v1">
  <Id>15446</Id>
  <Descripcion>Proyecto de Acuerdo N° 574</Descripcion>
  <Fecha>2012-06-13T14:47:29</Fecha>
  <TotalSi>12</TotalSi>
  <TotalNo>2</TotalNo>
  <TotalAbstencion>2</TotalAbstencion>
  <TotalDispensado>0</TotalDispensado>
  <Quorum Valor="1">Quórum Simple</Quorum>
  <Resultado Valor="2">Unánime</Resultado>
  <Tipo Valor="3">Proyecto de Acuerdo</Tipo>
  <Votos>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>810</Id>
        <Nombre>Gabriel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Ascencio</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Mansilla</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>855</Id>
        <Nombre>Carlos Abel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Jarpa</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Wevar</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>862</Id>
        <Nombre>Pablo</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Lorenzini</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Basso</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="0">En Contra</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>898</Id>
        <Nombre>Gabriel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Silber</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Romo</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
  </Votos>
</Votacion>
```

I got the data from this api
https://opendata.camara.cl/camaradiputados/WServices/WSLegislativo.asmx/retornarVotacionDetalle?prmVotacionId=15446

I want to process the data to obtain a  tibble like this (The "Votos" column have to be char type but with json format)

| Id (int) | Description (char) | Fecha (POSIXct) | Quorum (char) | Resultado (char) | Tipo (char) | Votos (char) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15446 | Proyecto de Acuerdo N° 574 | 2012-06-13T14:47:29 | Quórum Simple | Unánime | Proyecto de Acuerdo | {Id:810,Nombre:'Gabriel',ApellidoPaterno:'Acencio',ApellidoMaterno:'Mansilla',OpcionVoto:'Afirmativo'} |
| 15446 | Proyecto de Acuerdo N° 574 | 2012-06-13T14:47:29 | Quórum Simple | Unánime | Proyecto de Acuerdo | {Id:855,Nombre:'Abel',ApellidoPaterno:'Jarpa',ApellidoMaterno:'Webar',OpcionVoto:'Afirmativo'} |
| 15446 | Proyecto de Acuerdo N° 574 | 2012-06-13T14:47:29 | Quórum Simple | Unánime | Proyecto de Acuerdo | {Id:862,Nombre:'Pablo',ApellidoPaterno:'Lorenzini',ApellidoMaterno:'Basso',OpcionVoto:'En Contra'} |

Any kind of help will be amazing, please !!!